# Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit not working

Tags: 64-bit

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on my desktop that I use for testing hard/software. It was working fine. Trying the 12.10 version gives me blank screen with only the mouse pointer moving. PC is the same in both cases and hd is wiped clean in both cases before installation. Any thoughts why?

Answer (score -1):

Have you by any chance been downloading Graphics card drivers ? I had this probrlem with ubuntu 12.10 and I had to uninstall the proprietary 'fglrx' driver for AMD/ATI and this solved it?

Just a thought?